# init array with syntactic sugar ,which init method is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

Now i get a array, but which init method is called?

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(const ObjectType [])objects count:(NSUInteger)cnt;
+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(ObjectType)firstObj, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
+ (instancetype)arrayWithArray:(NSArray<ObjectType> *)array;
- (instancetype)initWithObjects:(ObjectType)firstObj, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray<ObjectType> *)array;
```

I hooked the upon init method, but got no luck;So here i am, which method exactly is called when using syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#container-literals), array literals expand to [`+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects:count:).

Comment: hoops, i have missed hooking the method;anyway, thanks a lot;the link is really helpful!!!